Paint peeling on bedframe
Paint peeling
Hi, this is my first time painting furniture and I did as much research as I could and got products I thought would work. I’ve painted a primer, a few layers of paint, and a topcoat sealant on some of the pieces of this bed:
https://www.templeandwebster.com.au/Campbell-Single-Bunk-Bed-TMPL5832.html
I went today to continue painting and I noticed that large pieces are peeling off in sheets and the primer isn’t adhering at all. Does anyone know where I’ve gone wrong and how to fix it? Would I be better off just getting some peel and stick wallpaper or something similar rather than trying to paint it all? I used British Paints 4 in 1 prep, and rustoleum black milk finish and rustoleum chalked Matt clear protective topcoat. Got everything from Bunnings. It doesn’t seem to make a difference if I’ve sanded or not sanded the pieces after a test but it might be I’m not sanding it down enough.

The milk paint I used seems really commonly used for furniture and all the reviews of it are for furniture so I’m assuming the issue is my primer?

Aha. A search found one (not sure if it is exactly the same, but probably close) Suitable for interior use on wood, metal, aluminum and glass I guess Rustoleum isn't just about painting over rust/preventing rust any more.

usually after priming one does a sticky test. using blue masking tape and see if primer comes off

What is the original finish? Is it a paint, a varnish, or a plastic? It is generally hard to get paint to adhere to melamine.

The listing says it’s PU Laminate? It’s got a hard shiny surface. Kinda reminds me of IKEA furniture.

I think you will need to sand the surface enough to rough it up.  Give the paint/primer something to bite/bond to.  This is assuming you gave the surface a good cleaning before to remove any dirt/dust/oils on the surface.

I did some where it was sanded and it’s peeling just the same unfortunately
